# How do remove the bottom scale on a Chart.js bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js to create the following chart:

[image]

The issue is that I want to make the scale at the bottom only show 0 and the maximum number (here being 12).

JavaScript:

`<script>
  new Chart(document.getElementById("leads-bar"), {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Hot", "Warm", "Cold"],
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: ["#d23232", "#ff9347", "#bbbbbb"],
          data: [7, 9, 11]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltips: {
        display: false
      },
      title: {
        display: false
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          stacked: true,
          gridLines: {
            display: false,
            drawBorder: false,
          },
          scaleShowLabels: false,
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          stacked: false,
          gridLines: {
            color: ["#eeeeee"]
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var dataArr = [154.23, 203.21, 429.01, 637.41];
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: [154.23, 203.21, 429.01, 637.41],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'LINE',
      data: dataArr,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)',
      fill: false,
      tension: 0
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: Math.min.apply(this, dataArr),
          max: Math.max.apply(this, dataArr),
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            if (index === values.length - 1) return Math.min.apply(this, dataArr);
            else if (index === 0) return Math.max.apply(this, dataArr);
            else return '';
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```